# Spring cloud config service unable to fetch from local uri

Tags: spring, git, spring-cloud

I am trying to load the configuration from my local file folder. It looks like it can get to the file folder defined. However, I am not sure what happened next

```
spring: 
cloud:
config:
  server:
    git:
      uri: file:../../company-config
      basedir: target/config
      searchPaths: '{application}/'
      repos:
        international-branch:
          pattern: inter*/*
          uri: file:../../inter-branch-config
          searchPaths: '{application}/'
```

I got the following error message. I don't understand why its still trying to clone from remote git repo rather just use files in this specified uri? Isn't it the purpose to config uri:file to avoid clone from remote?

```
2019-05-01 15:29:22.480  WARN 17312 --- [io-8888-exec-10] PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository : Could not fetch remote for development remote: ssh://git@xxx.com:7999/cir/xxxxx-config.git
2019-05-01 15:29:22.483 DEBUG 17312 --- [io-8888-exec-10] PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository : Stacktrace for: Could not fetch remote for development remote: ssh://git@xxxxx.com:7999/cir/xxx-config.git
```

And how come it failed to fetch it, as in the same terminal can pull from this repo.

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have some other configuration pointing at the remote?

Comment: Thanks Spencer. How is that configuration may look like? I don't see any other config in mine